# Проблема в том,что при сканировании(QrCode) чело-либо вылетает приложение

Tags: android, kotlin

В определенной части кода я пытаюсь найти все значения массива,чтобы узнать есть ли вообще qrкод схожий со сканированным для успешного сканирования.
Вот сама часть кода,где вылетает :

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        val result : IntentResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data)
        if(result != null) {
            if(result.contents == null) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            } else {
                val baseFragment = AddNoteFragment()
                    var i = 0
                    while(i == baseFragment.note!!.code.length){
                        when {
                            requestCode.toString() == baseFragment.note!!.code[i].toString() -> {
                                Toast.makeText(this, "Successfully Scanned", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                            }
                            i == baseFragment.note?.code?.length -> {
                                Toast.makeText(this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                            }
                            else -> {
                                Toast.makeText(this, "Undefined", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                            }
                        }
                        i++
                    }
            }
        } else {
            val home_fragment = SyncData()
            home_fragment.GetNoteData()
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Как минимум нужна ошибка из логката

Comment: Проблема в том,что на эмуляторе невозможно просканировать что-либо,так что не смогу показать ошибку.Но у меня скорее возник вопрос насчет правильности написания данного куска кода

Comment: Если у Вас вылетает, то, значит, Вы все-таки можете запустить приложение! Если что, для реальных устройств логкат тоже работает!

Comment: Если честно, то я вообще не понял, что Вы тут пытаетесь сделать, выглядит код очень странно

Comment: ну если уточнить,то вылетает приблизительно тогда,когда условие if переходит в else и начинается выполнятся код из else

Comment: ну...впрочем,если вам не удалось понять мой код,то в любом случае спасибо вам

Comment: Вот таким кодом `val baseFragment = AddNoteFragment()` и `val home_fragment = SyncData()` дорога в ад выстлана :) А в том аду логкат бесконечен и потому не скачивается ;)